# Передача двумерного массива в качестве аргумента функции

Tags: c, массивы

Никак не могу разобраться с передачей двумерного массива в функцию, и вывода его этой функцией на экран. И какими ещё способами можно передать двумерный массив в функцию?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printmas (int intmas[3][4])
{
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)  
   {
     for(int j=0; j<4; j++) 
       {
         printf("%d ", intmas[i][j]);
       }
     printf("\n"); 
   } 

}

int main ()

{
    int danmassiv [3][4]={{10,9,98,65},
                          {8,-9,-4,6},
                          {15,6,78,-8}};

    printmas(danmassiv);

}
```

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно и/или не работает? И каким боком тут C++ ?

Comment: конкретно не выводит заданный массив и я не могу разобраться какими способами можно отправить его в функцию

Comment: Скопировал этот код один в один. Всё прекрасно собирается, работает, передаётся и выводит. Компилятор - gcc 4.8.4. Кстати, на странице с вопросом (то есть этой же), справа, есть список смежных вопросов,под заголовком "Похожие". Там много чего по этой теме, гляньте.

Comment: спасибо за совет

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Могу скромно предположить, что Ваша функция printmas типа int, предполагает возвращение значения. Стоит попробовать сделать ее void.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Аргумент функции двумерный массив

```
int fun(int array[][])

int fun(int * array[])

int fun(int ** array)
```

Answer (score 4):

Первые скобки необходимо оставить пустыми, но все следующие необходимо заполнить, указав соответствующий размер. Это необходимо, чтобы компилятор мог определить глубину каждого дополнительного массива.

Таким образом:

```
int printmas (int intmas[][4]) {...}
```

Answer (score 4):

Может быть в общем случае лучше всего передавать в функцию размеры массива и адрес его первого элемента (т.е. представлять в функции этот массив как одномерный) и самостоятельно вычислять нужный индекс при обращении к элементам массива.

Например, для двумерного массива:

```
void pri_arr (int ncol, int nlines, int a[]) {
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < ncol || (puts(""), 0); j++)
      printf("%d ", a[i * ncol + j]);
}


int main()
{
  puts("2 dim");
  int a[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
         {11, 12, 13, 14},
         {21, 22, 23, 24}};
  pri_arr(4, 3, &a[0][0]);
}
```

Этот способ работает во всех Си и С++ компиляторах.

А вот в gcc (C, не С++) этот же пример можно написать и более естественным образом:

```
void pri_arr (int ncol, int nlines, int a[][ncol]) {
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < ncol || (puts(""), 0); j++)
      printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
}
```

Обратите внимание, количество элементов в строке массива должно передаваться **перед** его объявлением в списке аргументов.

```
int main()
{
  puts("2 dim");
  int a[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
         {11, 12, 13, 14},
         {21, 22, 23, 24}};
  pri_arr(4, 3, a);
}
```

При вызове передаем сам массив (а не адрес первого элемента, как в первом примере).

Answer (score 1):

gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 4
/*опишите прототип функции. Здесь int (*ar)[COL] указатель на массив из 4 элементов типа int */
void printmas(int (*ar)[COLS] , int rows);

int main(void)
{
/*задайте и проинициализируйте массив*/
    int danmassiv [ROWS][COLS]={
                      {10,9,98,65},
                      {8,-9,-4,6},
                      {15,6,78,-8}
                     };

    printf("Массив значений имеет вид:\n");
    /*вызовите функцию, передав ей имя массива как указатель на 1 элемент(массив из 4 значений типа int) и кол-во элементов в нем */
    printmas(danmassiv, ROWS);
    return 0;
}
/* определение функции */
void printmas(int ar[][COLS], int rows)
{
    int r;
    int c;
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
      for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
        /* печать элементов массива,- ar[r][c] указатель на каждый элемент массива  */
        printf("%d", ar[r][c]);
      printf("\n");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Вам важно понять, что в общем случае массивы и указатели тесно связаны друг с другом. Если ar есть
массив, то выражения ar [ i ] и * ( ar + i ) эквивалентны. Как только это станет понятным, все остальное встанет на свои места. Удачи.