# Как правильно передать двумерный массив в параметр функции С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Необходимо передать в функцию двумерный массив, вот код:

```
int proizvedenie(int a, int b, int **arr)
{
    int k=0, m=0, proizv=1;
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
        {
            if(arr[k][j]>0)
            {
                proizv*=arr[k][j];
            }
            else
            {
                m++;
                proizv=1;
            }
        }
        if(m==0)
            {
                std::cout<<"Произведение элементов "<<k+1<<" строки = "<<proizv<<std::endl;
            }
        else
            {
                std::cout<<k+1<<" строка имеет отрицательные элементы"<<std::endl;
            }
            proizv=1;
            k++;
            m=0;
    }
}
int diag(int a, int b, int **arr)
{
    int k=1, sum=0, sum1=0, sum2=0;
    for(int k=1; k<a; k++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
            {
                if(fabs(i-j)==k && (j-i)>0)
                {
                    sum+=arr[i][j];
                }
                else if(fabs(i-j)==k && (j-i)<0)
                {
                    sum2+=arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            if(sum>sum1)
            {
                sum1=sum;
            }
            if(sum2>sum1)
            {
                sum1=sum2;
            }
        }
        sum=0;
        sum2=0;
    }
    std::cout<<"Максимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы = "<<sum1;
}

main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a, b, k=0, sum=0, tr=1, sum2=0, proizv=1;
    std::cout<<"Введите количество строк: ";
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cout<<"Введите количество столбцов: ";
    std::cin>>b;
    int arr[a][b];
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=rand()%100-rand()%100;
            std::cout<<std::setw(b)<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    proizvedenie(a, b, arr);
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    diag(a, b, arr);
    return 0;
 }
```

При попытке вызвать функцию, выдает ошибку

> cannot convert 'int (*)[b]' to 'int**' for argument '3' to 'int proizvedenie(int, int, int**)'

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача двумерного массива в качестве аргумента функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531896/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Какая ошибка? Дополните статью ЛОГами, так будет понятно с чем имеем дело.

Comment: сделайте `(int**)(arr)` при вызове функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предпочитаю передавать двумерный массив  в функцию, как указатель, потому что двумерность, это лишь абстракция. На самом деле это одна последовательность

```
int proizvedenie(int a, int b, int *arr)
{
    int k=0, m=0, proizv=1;
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
        {
            if(arr[k * b + j]>0)
            {
                proizv*=arr[k * b + j];
            }
  //...
```

Дело в том, что  j-тый элемент к- той  строки, это и есть (k * b + j) - тый элемент в массиве

Теперь как использовать:

```
int m[4][5];
proizvedenie(4, 5, (int*)m);
```

или

```
proizvedenie(4, 5, m[0]);
```

m[0] это указатель на первый элемент первой строки, значит всего массива, ну а еще предпочтительней не использовать  массивы. Лучше конечно std::array и разновидности контейнеров и других последовательностей C++

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

int proizvedenie(int a, int b, int **arr)
{
    int k=0, m=0, proizv=1;
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
        {
            if(arr[k][j]>0)
            {
                proizv*=arr[k][j];
            }
            else
            {
                m++;
                proizv=1;
            }
        }
        if(m==0)
            {
                std::cout<<"Произведение элементов "<<k+1<<" строки = "<<proizv<<std::endl;
            }
        else
            {
                std::cout<<k+1<<" строка имеет отрицательные элементы"<<std::endl;
            }
            proizv=1;
            k++;
            m=0;
    }
}
int diag(int a, int b, int **arr)
{
    int k=1, sum=0, sum1=0, sum2=0;
    for(int k=1; k<a; k++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
            {
                if(fabs(i-j)==k && (j-i)>0)
                {
                    sum+=arr[i][j];
                }
                else if(fabs(i-j)==k && (j-i)<0)
                {
                    sum2+=arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            if(sum>sum1)
            {
                sum1=sum;
            }
            if(sum2>sum1)
            {
                sum1=sum2;
            }
        }
        sum=0;
        sum2=0;
    }
    std::cout<<"Максимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы = "<<sum1;
}

main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a, b, k=0, sum=0, tr=1, sum2=0, proizv=1;
    std::cout<<"Введите количество строк: ";
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cout<<"Введите количество столбцов: ";
    std::cin>>b;
    int arr[a][b];

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=rand()%100-rand()%100;
            std::cout<<std::setw(b)<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    proizvedenie(a, b, (int**)(arr));
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    diag(a, b, (int**)(arr));
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Теперь после ввода значений прога вовсе вылетает, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @Leithtp Вы пробовали заниматься отладкой ? Добавлять дебажный вывод или запускать в отладчике ? Это гораздо быстрее и полезнее чем ждать тут пока кто-нибудь отладит или просто посмотрев увидит ошибку в логике

Answer (score 0):

Если предполагается только читать данные из массива - используйте тот же тип, что и при объявлении, если необходимо использовать операции записи - нужно передать указатель на тип, используемый в объявлении (т.е. ***arr)

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int sz, int **arr);

int main() {
    const int sz = 10;
    int **arr = new int*[sz];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        arr[i] = new int[sz];

    f(sz, arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        delete arr[i];
    delete[] arr;
}

int f(int sz, int **arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < sz; ++j) 
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << "\n";
}
```